# How to change the color of the "equal" in Spyder？

Tags: spyder, data-analysis

I want to change the Spyder's color scheme like the sublime, include "=".
In Spyder, "=" is white like the normal text, I want change it into red.
But I can't find where to do this.

Spyder
[image]

Sublime
[image]

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It's not possible to do what you want, sorry.

Comment: and can you tell me why?

Comment: As you can see from our `Preferences`, we don't provide the option to do that.